# Generating Combinational string of length n using 3 possible values

Tags: algorithm

I have three possible values of war(w) ,buy(b) and sell(s). I have to generate a combinational string of length N.

Suppose N is 2 total combination is 3x3=9

```
w,w
w,b
w,s
b,w
b,b
b,s
s,w
s,b
s,s
```

likewise I have to generate a combinational string of (w,s,b) of size equals to N. 2<=N<=8000

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: So you need to create a permutation? Or maybe *all* permutations? Or do you really mean combinations? (For permutations, the numbers of each value are fixed, for combinations not.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a recursive function. Here's an example in python, but you can easily rewrite it in your favorite language.

```
def x(partial):
  if len(partial) == N:
    handle_solution(partial)
  for c in ('w', 'b', 's'):
    x(partial + c)
```

This is going to be slow regardless of language or implementation. The number of solutions is 3^N so even for relatively small values of N this will take a very long time. You should go back to your original problem and figure out a way to solve it without going through all the combinations.